# Barplot side by side and line charts in the same plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I want to create in R a plot which contains side by side bars and line charts as follows:

[image: https://www.corona-os.de/startseite/]

I tried:

```
Total <- c(584,605,664,711,759,795,863,954,1008,1061,1117,1150)
Infected <- c(366,359,388,402,427,422,462,524,570,560,578,577)
Recovered <- c(212,240,269,301,320,359,385,413,421,483,516,548)
Death <- c(6,6,7,8,12,14,16,17,17,18,23,25)
day <- itemizeDates(startDate="01.04.20", endDate="12.04.20")

df <- data.frame(Day=day, Infected=Infected, Recovered=Recovered, Death=Death, Total=Total)

value_matrix = matrix(, nrow = 2, ncol = 12)
value_matrix[1,] = df$Recovered
value_matrix[2,] = df$Death

plot(c(1:12), df$Total, ylim=c(0,1200), xlim=c(1,12), type = "b", col="peachpuff", xaxt="n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
points(c(1:12), df$Infected, type = "b", col="red")
barplot(value_matrix, beside = TRUE, col = c("green", "black"), width = 0.35, add = TRUE)
```

But the bar chart does not fit the line chart. I guess it would be easier to use ggplot2, but don't know how. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ggplot2, the margins are handled nicely for you, but you'll need the data in two separate long forms. Reshape from wide to long with `tidyr::gather`, `tidyr::pivot_longer`, `reshape2::melt`, `reshape`, or whatever you prefer.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2) 

df <- data.frame(
    Total = c(584,605,664,711,759,795,863,954,1008,1061,1117,1150),
    Infected = c(366,359,388,402,427,422,462,524,570,560,578,577),
    Recovered = c(212,240,269,301,320,359,385,413,421,483,516,548),
    Death = c(6,6,7,8,12,14,16,17,17,18,23,25),
    day = seq(as.Date("2020-04-01"), as.Date("2020-04-12"), by = 'day')
)

ggplot(
    tidyr::gather(df, Population, count, Total:Infected), 
    aes(day, count, color = Population, fill = Population)
) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_col(
        data = tidyr::gather(df, Population, count, Recovered:Death), 
        position = 'dodge', show.legend = FALSE
    )
```

[image: plot with lines and bars]

Another way to do it is to gather twice before plotting. Not sure if this is easier or harder to understand, but you get the same thing.

```r
df %>% 
    tidyr::gather(Population, count, Total:Infected) %>% 
    tidyr::gather(Resolution, count2, Recovered:Death) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = day, y = count, color = Population)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_col(
        aes(y = count2, color = Resolution, fill = Resolution), 
        position = 'dodge', show.legend = FALSE
    )
```

[image: same plot]

You can actually plot the lines and points without reshaping by making separate calls for each, but to dodge bars (or get legends), you'll definitely need to reshape.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I want. Thank you.